# override twitter bootstrap doesn't work for some reason

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

so my page header look like this:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and inside style.css i have:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FDFDFD;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
```

however, when the page loads, i see that the bootstrap css class override mine and not vice versa. Am i missing something here? could it be because i'm using the cached version (i don't think so). See attached image

[image]

please advise.

Comment: Can you post the html code?

Comment: you added bootstrap two times. one overwrite the other

Comment: where do you the 2nd second link?

Comment: Can you check and see if the styles.css file is infact the last one getting loaded as it should be. Ideally it should looking at your header, but sometimes, loading from CDN and certain scripts can get in the way causing your custom styles to get loaded first and the cdn one to load later.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should specify more your css rule like

```
#something .nav div.navbar-default
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Please let me know if it is a sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` after the CSS rule but before the semi colon inside your CSS rules.

Comment: but shouldn't the last css the define should take over?

Comment: You would think so, but I've seen strange things happen when trying to overrule bootstrap.

Comment: basically it is not a good idea to use `!important`. It should be use only if there is no other options.

Comment: Smefju - correct, however, when calling bootstrap via CDN, this is the best solution to ensure the rules are overridden.

Comment: Not really. You can reach the same results using more specified css rules. Firstly you include bootstrap via CDN and than your own styles, so you can overwrite bootstrap rules in your styles.

Comment: how do you do it smefju/

Comment: @OrA i give you an example in answer above ;) - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20336405/1941418.